# Does SQL Server Report (SSRS 2008) have event procedure?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I am new to SSRS reports. Before this I have used similar kind of technologies like Oracle Developer Reports or MS Access Reports. My question here is: does SQL Reports have event procedures? By this I mean if we want to do some processing on every data row, or on before/after each group, can we write event procedures/functions at these events?

The scenario is this; In a typical Employees report, I want to define a variable that categorizes employees based on their salary, and for each row we compute that variable as per following logic;

```
IF sal BETWEEN 1000 AND 1999 THEN
   Emp_Tag = 'Lower Middle'
   Count_low_mid += 1
ELSIF sal BETWEEN 2000 AND 2999 THEN
   Emp_Tag = 'Average'
   Count_average += 1
ELSIF sal BETWEEN 3000 AND 3999 THEN
   Emp_Tag = 'Above Average'
   Count_abv_avg += 1
.... and so on ...
END IF
```

And then at the end we can calculate the counts of each category of employees (Count_low_mid, Count_average, Count_abv_avg). Can anybody please tell me how can I implement this kind of logic in sql server reports (SSRS)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by apply a conditional aggregate in a table header row. Say I have some sample data like this:

[image]

And a table with header rows only:

[image]

The expressions for the respective groups are:

**Lower Middle**

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!sal.Value >= 1000 and Fields!sal.Value < 2000, 1, 0))
```

**Average**

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!sal.Value >= 2000 and Fields!sal.Value < 3000, 1, 0))
```

**Above Average**

```
=Sum(IIf(Fields!sal.Value >= 3000 and Fields!sal.Value < 4000, 1, 0))
```

These expressions simply count all rows that fulfill certain criteria, giving the required results:

[image]

Alternatively, set up a Calculated Field with an expression like:

```
=Switch(Fields!sal.Value >= 1000 and Fields!sal.Value < 2000, "Lower Middle"
  , Fields!sal.Value >= 2000 and Fields!sal.Value < 3000, "Average"
  , Fields!sal.Value >= 3000 and Fields!sal.Value < 4000, "Above Average")
```

And set up a group based on this, which will give the same result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Preston. Your answer is really helpful. But it also strengthen my thinking that SSRS Report do not have event procedures like Oracle Developer Reports. So, we must use alternate logic on fixed row processing. But anyways, Thanks again.